# What am I? Time's own end

Tags: riddle

```
I am dying at each set and i am born on each rise
No one has seen me or will see me but i am always there
I dont move and always stay where i am  
I will live on, until time's own end
What am I?
```

A riddle i made, inspired by another little riddle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are:

> Tomorrow.

I am dying at each set and i am born on each rise

> Tomorrow stops being tomorrow (dies) and starts being today - and moving to the next day (reborn).

No one has seen me or will see me but i am always there

> If you see tomorrow, it is "today".

I dont move and always stay where i am

> Tomorrow is always out of reach at a constant range from where we are.

I will live on, until time's own end

> There will always be a "tomorrow" until the end of time.

Comment: Nice one. But wasn't really a difficult one i guess

Comment: If this is right, how about 'I am thrice invoked by a Scottish king' as a new line?

Comment: @Taacoo I'm surprised I was right. It is very nice. Classic style

Comment: @randal'thor explain?

Comment: @Taacoo http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macbeth CTRL+F "tomorrow"

Comment: @d'alar'cop - Beat me to it! http://www.enotes.com/shakespeare-quotes/tomorrow-tomorrow-tomorrow

Comment: @randal'thor your link is better :p